# Get total Qty of Items Ordered in Create Order in Magento Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, qty

I want to Sum up all the QTY of each all items.

I added another column, actually I just removed the Colspan.

I want all QTY to be summed up.

[image]

Then thses are the files that I adjusted

For view

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/items/grid.phtml
```

And for the Controller

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Items/grid.php
```

This is my code

```
public function gettotalquantity()
{
    $totalqty = 1;
    $items = $this->getParentBlock()->getItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $totalqty = $totalqty + $item->getQty();
    }
}
```

Kindly advice as it returns an error NUll.

Am I going the right way, newbie here in Magento.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//I thing you miss the return value line.

```
public function gettotalquantity()
{
    $totalqty = 1;
    $items = $this->getParentBlock()->getItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $totalqty = $totalqty + $item->getQty();
    }
    return $totalqty; // New line added by me.
}
```